# Wordpress: Multiple taxonomy terms in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I am trying to get multiple taxonomy terms in WP_Query. Here is my code:

```
$category = get_field('portfolio_category');  //array of IDs like 14, 15, 16

            <?php
            $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'         => 'projects',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'projectCategories',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => array( implode(', ', $category ) ),
                        'operator' => 'AND'
                    )
                ),
            ));
            ?>
```

The problem is in the current code I can only query the very first term.
For example I can only get projects from cat ID=14.
What am I doing wrong here? How can I query posts from multiple terms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$category` is already an array... change your `terms` value to just `$category`.  so your full query would be:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'projectCategories',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $category,
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    ),
));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solved the issue. In my case I needed to remove the operator too.